# what is: is_paying_customer field in woocommerce rest api

Tags: node.js, woocommerce, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce rest api.
when I retrieve a user (customer) using node.js with this code:

```
    WooCommerce.get('customers/25', function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I get a field named "is_paying_customer"; what is the meaning and usage of this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The user already completed a order in the store**

Here is where this attribute is set: *includes/wc-user-functions.php~280*

```
/**
 * Order payment completed - This is a paying customer.
 *
 * @param int $order_id Order ID.
 */
function wc_paying_customer( $order_id ) {
    $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $customer_id = $order->get_customer_id();
    if ( $customer_id > 0 && 'shop_order_refund' !== $order->get_type() ) {
        $customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );
        if ( ! $customer->get_is_paying_customer() ) {
            $customer->set_is_paying_customer( true );
            $customer->save();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_paying_customer' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_paying_customer' );
```

Check the add_action function in the end, when the hook *woocommerce_payment_complete* or *woocommerce_order_status_completed* are called, woocommerce will set "is_paying_customer" to TRUE.